# How to write jPOS service

Tags: java, javapos

I have a PoS device which is created by me. Now I want to connect my device to PoS computer. For that as I have to write my own jPOS service. 
I searched for a sample or tutorial for days, but I couldn't find any.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [jpos114.jar](http://www.javapos.com/downloads/JavaPOS-1.14.0-Dist.zip).
2. Add this jar file into your project and create a new class to implement the service. For example:`public class MyLineDisplay implements LineDisplay114` and implement the functions you will use.
3. Export the service to be a jar file for developing JavaPOS application or you can just use Postest/Postest2 to test device service.
4. Create a jpos.xml file to write down the information of your device service for device control to connect to the device service. Postest/Postest2 also include jpos.xml and you can refer to it.